# How does ^ (handle to object operator) works?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I can remove last char from textBox by

```
textBox1->Text = textBox1->Text->Remove(textBox1->Text->Length - 1);
```

And I want to do it creating a reference or a pointer to the Text. But I can't do it like this

```
String^ t = textBox1->Text;
t = t->Remove(t->Length - 1); // Text doesn't change
```

---

P.S. Any of this doesn't compile:

```
String* t = textBox1->Text; // error: an ordinary pointer to a
                            // C++/CLI ref class or interface class
                            // is not allowed

String& t = textBox1->Text; // error: an ordinary reference to a
                            // C++/CLI ref class or interface class
                            // is not allowed

String% t = textBox1->Text // error: a tracking reference to a
                           // System::String is not allowed
```

Comment: Strings in .NET are immutable. Store a reference to the TextBox control, instead.

Comment: @CodyGray: Just out of curiosity (I'm not familiar with c++ cli), what is the likely type of `textBox1` here?

Comment: @CodyGray, but doesn't `t->Remove` create a new String?

Comment: @cheers It would be System::Windows::Forms::TextBox, which is a derived class of System::Windows::Forms::Control.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, it's `System::Windows::Forms::TextBox` (in this case I can use `auto`)

Comment: Sure, `Remove` returns a new String object, but that doesn't help you here, @pavel. The issue is that System::String is immutable, so you cannot assign it.

Comment: @CodyGray, so can we say that `^` is more similar not to `*` but to `&`? If yes, what is the difference with this http://pastebin.com/gzb4RpHB ?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point that System::String is immutable. It is not a problem with the `^` operator.

Comment: You are looking for a *reference*.  That's supported in C++/CLI, it is `String^%`.  But you'll be in for a rude surprise when you try to use it, properties are a very leaky abstraction in a language that supports references.  Big reason why C++ doesn't have them.  If you need an extra level of indirection then you need to use a delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = t->Remove(t->Length - 1);
```

just changes the local reference (pointer-thingy, handle, …) `t`, to refer to the string returned by `Remove`.

The textbox string isn't changed by that.

When you do

```
textBox1->Text = t;
```

… you're calling a **setter function** for the **property** `Text`, and this setter function not just changes the textbox string data, but updates or at least invalidates the textbox display.

Comment: But why a setter function isn't called when I write `t = [new String object]`?

Comment: @Pavel because `t` is just a local variable while `TextBox::Text` is a property (a getter/setter pair under the hood).